# Multi-level paging tables

Tags: operating-systems, memory, cpu

Referring to the image here:

[image: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:X86_Paging_4K.svg]

<sub>From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:X86_Paging_4K.svg</sub>

Could somebody please explain something for me? I don't get exactly how this works. As I understand it the page "directory" contains an entity which essentially points to the beginning of the "page table". However, surely all of the entities in the page "directory" would contain the exact same value? Or, does this mean we have 1x page "directory" but N page "tables" (at the same level in the page multi-level hierarchy")?

If there are N page "tables" and one page "directory" I get why the PD would point to one of the N PTs. If there aren't then I am really confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

N page tables.

If you look at the [Wikipedia entry for Page Tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table), you'll see two diagrams there; one for the two-level page table structure, and one for the three-level page table structure.  The purpose of the three-level page table structure is to implement [PAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension), which allows memory access beyond 4GB.

Comment: Ok but the N isn't referring to the '2' or '3', the N is referring to how many instances at a particular level, right? Its saying "there are N simultaneous page tables for this particular level in the paging hierarchy"

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  There should only be one page directory table, but multiple page tables.

Answer (score 0):

That diagram should be read as:

1. The Page Directory (PD) is an array of Page Directory Entries (PDEs), pointed to by Control Register 3 (CR3).
2. The leftmost 10 bits of the address are used as an index into the PD.  The PDE at that position points to one of many Page Tables (PTs), specifically the PT that maps pages for the desired address.
3. The next 10 bits are used as an index into the PT.  The Page Table Entry (PTE) at that position points to one of many 4KB pages in memory, specifically the page that contains the desired address.
4. The rightmost 12 bits are used as a byte-index into the page.

Thus the memory location is at `CR3 -> [a & 0xffc00000] -> [a & 0x003ff000] -> [a & 0x00000fff]`